# Combinations Variant, Limit Choices for each position

Tags: python, combinations, permutation, sample

Hello I have a pool of 25 different choices that needs to have 5 choices picked from.

For all possible combinations, I think it is calculated as

`combinations(range(25), 5)`

But I have the limitation of requiring that the choices remain in certain positions

position 1 available picks

`[0, 1, 2, 3, 4]`

position 2 available picks

`[5, 6, 7, 8, 9]`

etc

I would like to find out how many combinations are available making sure to take into account that 0 - 4 could only be available in position 1, and 5-9 could only be available in position 2,

I have almost no experience in statistics and was just wondering what this type of sampling is called?

Thank you

Comment: If you know what lists of values should be in each position, just use `product` on the list of lists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe I didn't understand your question, but isn't it simply 5<sup>5</sup>? That is: `<number-of-avalailable-picks-for-each-position> ^ <number-of-positions>`.

For position 1, you have 5 possible choices, and for each of them you have 5 choices for position 2, and for each of those 25 choices you have 5 choices for postion 3, etc.

Now if the possible picks for each position are of different sizes, the number of choices is the product of the sizes of the pick lists. Translated into Python:

```
choicesLists = [
  [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7],
  [24, 23, 22, 21, 20, 19, 18, 17, 16, 15],
  [8, 14],
  [9, 13],
  [10, 11, 12]
]
nbChoices = reduce(lambda x,y: x*len(y), choicesLists)
```

And if you want to have the whole list of choices using itertools, you can use `product` as suggested by Dan D.:

```
combinations = product(*choicesList)
```

Comment: It happens :) Completed the question, as this was a python question

Answer (score 1):

The result is `5**5`

As, for 1st position you can choose in <sup>5</sup>C<sub>1</sub> = 5 way.
So you can do for 2nd position. And as for both first and second position you can choose in
5*5 way.
And thus for 5 positions the answer would be 5<sup>5</sup> or `5**5`.